# change an array depending on whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I am quite new to javascript. Any help very appreciated.

I have created a simplified example for easier explanation. I want to change a `finalArray` according to whether the checboxes are checked or unchecked.

So for example if `friends` and `strangers` checkboxes are checked then the `finalArray_` should = `["friend1" ,"friend2", "stranger1", "stranger2"]`.

If only `enemies` checkbox is checked then the `finalArray_` should = `["enemy1" ,"enemy2"]`. And so on.

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="friends_"> Friends <br />
        <!-- other code and functionality -->
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="enemies_"> Enemies <br />
        <!-- other code and functionality -->
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="strangers_"> Strangers <br />

    <script>
        const friends_ = ["friend1","friend2"];
        const enemies_ = ["enemy1","enemy2"];
        const strangers_ = ["stranger1","stranger2"];
    </script>
</body>
```

I tried this, but I know it's a crappy solution that doesn't work because I can't concat a string like this.

```
<script>
    const friends_ = ["friend1", "friend2"];
    const enemies_ = ["enemy1", "enemy2"];
    const strangers_ = ["stranger1", "stranger2"];

    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
                checked_boxes = Array.from(checkboxes).filter(i => i.checked).map(i => i.dataset.id).join();
                const finalArray = [].concat(checked_boxes);
                console.log(finalArray); //Array [ "friends_,strangers_" ]
            })
        })
</script>
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: So you want the selected check boxes to be in the array?

Comment: yes and update the array dynamically every time checkboxes change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I joined the different units into a single object so I can use the data-id as a key to get the array.

I haven't ran it since I made this on my phone, but you can try it and it should work.

ED:

I've changed it on my computer now. Should run and show you the output when clicking the checkboxes.

ED2:

I moved all the logic into a function which is called on pageload and when a checkbox is toggled.

```js
const units = {
  friends_: ["friend1", "friend2"],
  enemies_: ["enemy1", "enemy2"],
  strangers_: ["stranger1", "stranger2"],
}

let selectedUnits = [];

const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

checkBoxes.forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener("change", updateUnits));

document.onload = updateUnits();

function updateUnits() {
  selectedUnits = Array.from(checkBoxes)
    .filter(elm => elm.checked)
    .flatMap(elm => units[elm.getAttribute('data-id')]);
  console.clear();
  console.log(selectedUnits);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="friends_" checked> Friends <br />
  <!-- other code and functionality -->
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="enemies_"> Enemies <br />
  <!-- other code and functionality -->
  <input type="checkbox" data-id="strangers_"> Strangers <br />
</body>
```

Comment: there is an Uncaught TypeError: checkBoxes.filter is not a function

I'll check it.

Comment: Try it now. checkBoxes it a node list, so I had to convert it to an array first using Array.from().

Comment: yeah, it works great! i noticed that if i set some checkbox as checked by default (for example `<input type="checkbox" checked data-id="friends_"> Friends <br />`, the program doesn't work properly as before. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `dict` using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and `obj` of `key-value` pairs of `checkbox` data.

When a checkbox is checked then you can toggle its `id` in `dict` and then get results by iterating `dict`

```js
const friends_ = ["friend1", "friend2"];
const enemies_ = ["enemy1", "enemy2"];
const strangers_ = ["stranger1", "stranger2"];

const dict = new Set();
const obj = { friends_, enemies_, strangers_ };

const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll( "input[type=checkbox]" );
checkboxes.forEach( function ( checkbox ) {
    checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function (e) {
        const id = e.target.dataset.id;
        if(dict.has(id)) dict.delete(id);
        else dict.add(id);

        const result = [];
        for(let key of dict) result.push(...obj[key])
        console.log(result);
    } )
} )
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-id="friends_" id="Friends" />
<label for="Friends">Friends</label>
<!-- other code and functionality -->
<input type="checkbox" data-id="enemies_" id="Enemies" />
<label for="Enemies">Enemies</label>
<!-- other code and functionality -->
<input type="checkbox" data-id="strangers_" id="Strangers" />
<label for="Strangers">Strangers</label>
```